# Saving data to MacOS python application

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, dylib

I am using `Pyinstaller` to create my Python app from a set of scripts. This script uses a library that saves downloaded data to the `'~/'` directory (using the `os.join` function).

I was wondering how to edit the code in the library so that when it runs, it saves data to inside the app (like in the package, the Contents/Resources maybe)?

Comment: are you doing it using `--onefile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering how to edit the code in the library so that when it runs, it saves data to inside the app

Don't do that. This isn't a standard practice in macOS applications, and will fail in some standard system configurations. For example, it will fail if the application is used by a non-administrator user, or if the application is run from a read-only disk image or network share.

More importantly, it'll also make it difficult or impossible to sign the application bundle with a developer certificate.

Comment: Thanks for that! So would you suggest storing the data in a folder, '~/NewAppData/' or somewhere else on the file system that is accessible? Should I use a hidden folder to do this?

Comment: The typical location would be `~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/` -- replacing "MyApp" with your application name, of course.